# Regarding primitive element theorem

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I need some help regarding an explicit example in which $F(a)$ and $F(b)$ are different fields and the conditions for Primitive element theorem hold but $F(a,b) \neq F(a+b)$ that is $1$ doesn't work as the constant. Some other constant is compulsorily needed so that $F(a,b)=F(a+cb)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2})$$ this has degee $6$. However
$$\sqrt[3]{2}+\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2}=-\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]{2}$$ has degree $3$.